# Cypress - programmatically manipulating Angular/NGRX app

Tags: angular, ngrx, cypress

How do you programmatically interact with Angular/NGRX from Cypress? The cypress docs seem to refer only to React: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/11/14/testing-redux-store/

```
// expose store when run in Cypress
if (window.Cypress) {
  window.store = store
}
cy
 .window()
 .its('store')
 .invoke('dispatch', { type: 'ADD_TODO', text: 'Test dispatch' })
// check if the app has updated its UI
```

This would be the React approach; so what about Angular?

Comment: cypress is made to simulate a user behavior. Why would you want to interact with the store directly? It's to build e2e tests so if you need to mock data, mock them at the HTTP level using cy.server and cy.route

Comment: @maxime1992 see the linked blog article. This question is definitely debatable. I have discussed it with other developers on meetups and the majority would agree with you (not the main dev of cypress though, see blog). But IMHO as long as you can guarantee (!!!) getting to one certain app state by UI, you could set it up programatically to be used as a starting point for other tests. The benefit would be speed. The downsides would be misusing e2e tests for unit-testing and obfuscation for non-developers checking out the test-execution in the browser.

Comment: my problem is that I want take the state indicator from store to indicate that all stats are loaded and indicate that I can run cypress test. Other wise I got race condition and cypress runs before my page are fully loaded.. but I can't get state from ngrx store directly in cypress

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Angular it is almost the same. In your `AppComponent` or wherever you have the store you can do something like:

```
// Expose the store
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>){
        if(window.Cypress){
            window.store = this.store;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then create your own Cypress utility:

```
function dispatchAction(action: Action): Cypress.Chainable<any> {
    return cy.window().then(w => {
        const store = w.store;
        store.dispatch(action);
    });
}
```

And finally you can use it in a Cypress test:

```
dispatchAction(new MyAction()).then(() => {
     // Assert the side effect of your action
     // ...
     // cy.get('.name').should('exist');
});
```

Comment: Where do you place the Cypress utility function?

Comment: how do you access the state ? I want to wait a state equals true then continue my test..

Comment: @milesmeow You can place it in your test file or in a utility file

Answer (score 0):

You can access State like this (works in addition to the already accepted answer):

```
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

 

 cy.window().its('store').then((store: any) => {
   firstValueFrom(store.source).then((state) => {
     cy.log('got state', state);
   });
 });
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @D.Nykl This solution works only if you follow the accepted answer to make the store known to cypress. The state access can also be placed in a utility file

Comment: @Huantao see for solution to access state in cypress