# How to use Angular Store in Cypress e2e tests

Tags: angular, cypress, store, angular-e2e

I need to inject a value (dispatch an action) in my Angular Store in order to make my Cypress e2e tests to work. Indeed, I need my store to contain { isLoggedIn : true } to access any page in the app, otherwise user is redirected to the login page.
I found a similar question here [Cypress - programmatically manipulating Angular/NGRX app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542554/cypress-programmatically-manipulating-angular-ngrx-app), but the answer does not seem to work in my case.
**I always get the error: "cy.its() waited for the specified property store to exist, but it never did."**
None of the console.log are printed in the console of cypress when running the test.
*Here is my code in app.component.ts*

```
export interface IWindowCypress {
  store: Store;
  Cypress: unknown;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(protected store: Store) {
    const windowWithStore: IWindowCypress = window as unknown as IWindowCypress;
    console.log('AppComponent');
    if (windowWithStore.Cypress) {
      console.log('save store');
      windowWithStore.store = store;
    }
  }
}
```

*Here is my cypress test*

```
describe('ContactListComponent', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.window().its('store').invoke('dispatch', { type: '[User Effect] Load user success', user: { isLoggedIn : true } });
  });

// some tests
```

So I wonder what I am missing here or what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help ? Thank you !
PS: If I run my app with `npm run start` I have "AppComponent" printed in the console

Comment: Hi @TCH, I am stuck with the same issue, did you fond a way to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I gave up testing actions with Cypress, only UI stuffs

Answer (score 4):

This difference between your code and the reference question is

```js
window.store = this.store;   // referring to component instance store property
```

I'm not sure why the injected `store` isn't working, but try

```js
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(protected store: Store) {
    const windowWithStore: IWindowCypress = window as unknown as IWindowCypress;
    if (windowWithStore.Cypress) {
      windowWithStore.store = this.store;
    }
  }
}
```

You might also want the interface properties to be optional since they are not always present.

```js
export interface IWindowCypress {
  store?: Store;
  Cypress?: unknown;
}
```